# Task.IsComplited до реального завершения задачи

Tags: c#, tpl, task

Создаю кучу `Task` - в каждом игровой цикл, помещаю их в `List<Task>`:

```
GamesList.Add(gp.ContinueWith(t=>GamesList.Remove(t)));
```

Но они почему-то удаляются из списка до того как игровой цикл завершится - игра при этом идет спокойненько. Wtf?

Comment: Вы работаете со списком из разных потоков без синхронизации? Хм.

Comment: Да это не суть. Мне больше интересно, почему мои таски завершаются мгновенно, не завершаясь при этом.

Comment: Почему ваш таск завершается, это нужно спросить у вас. Приведите код создания таска. В вопросе его нет.

Comment: С изначальной проблемой разобрался - как обычно "сам дурак". Зачем-то было внутри таска `Task.Factory.StartNew` - видимо осталось от старого кода.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы добавляете в список не тот таск, который вы удаляете.

`ContinueWith` возвращает *новый* таск, а пытаетесь удалять вы первоначальный таск.

И да, вы **не должны** работать со списком из разных потоков без блокировки. Ну то есть вы можете, но не удивляйтесь тогда потерянным данным.

---

Попробуйте заменить `GamesList` на потокобезопасную коллекцию, и используйте

```
GamesList.Add(gp);
gp.ContinueWith(t=>GamesList.Remove(t));
```

Comment: Замечания приняты. Спасибо.

Comment: @Сергей: Пожалуйста! Работает с этими изменениями?

Comment: Да,  конечно. Там еще был баг, который я процессе обнаружил (в комментариях к вопросу описал).

Comment: @Сергей: Ага, понял. Вот и хорошо.